# Square Root Of A Number In Python

Tags: python

I created a program where you can either roll a dice or find the square root of a number. These options can be toggled with the numbers 1 and 2. Howvever, whenever I want to find the square root of a number, it gives me the square root of the number I want and the square root of 2. How do I solve this? Code is below:
Please disregard indentation errors as Stack Overflow was giving me a tough time putting the code in.

```
from random import randint
import math

UserInput = int(input("To Roll A Dice, Type One. To Find The Square Root Of A 
Number, Press 2 "))
    while True:
        if UserInput == 1:
            print (randint(1, 6))

        if UserInput == 2:
            print(math.sqrt(int(input("What Number Would You Like To Find The Square Root Of? "))))
```

And This is my Result when I want to find the square root of 16:

```
 To Roll A Dice, Type One. To Find The Square Root Of A Number, Press 2 2
 What Number Would You Like To Find The Square Root Of? 16
 4.0
 1.4142135623730951
```

Comment: Fix your indentation.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior. Have you checked you indention?

Comment: I ran the script and it looked fine, so it's likely the indentation issue. Make sure the two if statements are in line with each other, and consider changing the format to if/elif/else

Comment: Is a infinite loop really necessary, and if so why, what is the purpose of putting the code inside an infinite loop?

Comment: We can't disregard the indentation errors. Indentation is critical to correct parsing of Python. Paste your original code into the editor, then use the `{}` tool to indent it as code.

Comment: I checked my indentation. I don't think that is the problem because python does not give me any syntax or indentation errors wen I run it through the debugger or test it

Comment: [How to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: You also can't have a newline in the `To Roll A Dice` string. Please post the actual script, this is obviously not a faithful copy of it.

Comment: When I fixed the newline and indentation I couldn't reproduce your problem either.

Comment: The `1.414...` output must be coming from other code that you haven't shown us.

Comment: My guess is you have something like `print(sqrt(UserInput))` somewhere.

Comment: I will upload a screenshot of how my code looks in the editor I am using (Pycharm)

Comment: @HowToTutorials -- no, don't post a screen shot.  Post the code, per the posting guidelines.

Comment: @HowToTutorials Yeah I ran this code and it worked fine. So unless you have other code that you have not posted here, this code does not have the error you claim.

Comment: @JohnGordon The code I have shown is all the code I have written. 1.414 is coming from the square root of two. What I think my issue is is that my code is showing the square root of two as well as the square root of the number i want to find the square root of.

Comment: As far as I can see, there is nothing in your posted code that would print the square root of 2.  Therefore, other code must also be executing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue with your code as bad indentation as stated in the comments. In addition, I see no need for an infinite loop as that will either repeatedly roll and repeatedly square root, unless that is your goal.
Here is my code:

```
from random import randint
import math

UserInput = int(input("To Roll A Dice, Type One. To Find The Square Root Of A Number, Press 2 "))
if UserInput == 1:
    print (randint(1, 6))

elif UserInput == 2:
    print(math.sqrt(int(input("What Number Would You Like To Find The Square Root Of? "))))
```

That is unless you want to repeatedly ask for user input In which case put the while loop above the creation of the User Input variable.

Edit: If you really do want re usability then use `def` to make this a function and have the following code

```
while True:
    play = input("Do you want to play? y/n")
    if play == "y":
        function_name()
    elif play == "n":
        break
```